# Finding replacement for antediluvian lock

Tags: doors, lock, latches

I would like to replace an internal lock on the cupboard door in my flat. The lock is very old and I struggle to find a similar type in B&Q. I can mostly find locks that are to be mounted inside the door not on the side, like the one I have. I'm looking to learn the following:

1. Does this type of lock have a proper name so I can search Amazon, eBay and find something similar?
2. Judging by the provided dimensions, is anyone in position to suggest a potentially suitable replacement?

[image: Measuers]
[image: Outside]
[image: Door]

Comment: What is "B&Q"? .

Comment: @isherwood in the UK: https://www.diy.com

Comment: A reason to avoid the use of store names such as Harbor freight - some do not recognise them...

Comment: You might get lucky & after an overnight bath in Nitromors it might turn out to be brass… & salvageable.

Comment: Unlikely to be brass, judging from the thickness of the plate. I wouldn't have thought it would be strong enough. Brass locks are generally (in my experience at least) cast rather than stamped / formed.

Comment: What has been done to the battery in the second photo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [rim lock](https://www.toolstation.com/rim-lock-with-handles/p79578)
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's similar, but the OP's looks like simply a tongue that locks the door - the knob isn't part of the mechanism. On a cupboard door, there's no need for a knob inside. It wouldn't hurt, maybe. Although it may catch on anything inside. But both knobs could be left off?

Comment: Good point. Rim locks are available without knobs - this was just the first one that Google showed me :)  Picture added of a better match, which I found on an eBay listing.

Comment: I’ve actually figured that in the UK, this type of lock is often described as ‘rim deadlock’. The first picture looks like ‘rim sashlock’.

Comment: @Konrad - Then we've *both* learnt something today :)